# Save in Continue of CSV or Xlsx File

Tags: excel, gridview, csv, xlsx

I want update my gridview and then save gridview content in continue Of my csv or xlsx file. after that update my gridview again, then save content in continue of file :

Example :

Gridview content1:

save in : Column 1 - 255

Gridview content2:

save in : Column 256 - 500

...

How can i save in continue of same file ??? (Dont Overwrite in past Columns)

Ex for my bad english :)

My Saving code :

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();

        ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

        ExcelApp.Columns.ColumnWidth = 20;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count; j++)
            {

                ExcelApp.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();

            }

        }

        if (!textBox1.Text.Contains(".xlsx"))
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(".xls", ".xlsx");
        }

        ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(textBox1.Text);

        ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;

        ExcelApp.Quit();
```

And My Import From excel file (Select Range Of column is 255) :

```
            string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;""", txtPath.Text);
            string query = String.Format("select * from [CA:DA]", "Sheet1");
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

This cuased for big excel file! it have 15000 column!

```
try
        {

            for (int row = 0; row <= dataGridView1.RowCount-1; row++)
            {
                for (int cell = 0; cell <= dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count-1; cell++)
                {         
                    string cellst = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[cell].Value.ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[cell].Value = Int64.Parse(cellst) + 1;

                    }
                }
            }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data Format Error. Please Review your file for not numeric data!");
      }
```

Comment: Where is your gridview? In a separate app you are developing?

Comment: What are you developing your app in? How are you accessing excel? Are you using C# and getting to Excel through the interop...?

Comment: Can you post some code of how you are 'saving your gridview'? From there perhaps someone can help you extend it to append like you want it to

Comment: C#, Yes Excel Intropt Used, I want resolved my 255 limit of column i can import in gridview with OLEDB. I think, i can load my data in range of 255 column in gridview and go for save in file, then clear gridview for next 255 , ...

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Also is your problem that you don't know how to add columns at a specific point, or that you have reached the limit of the amount of columns excel is allowing you? 255 columns is a lot of columns... how many rows in each column? Is it not possible to transpose this and rather have 1-255 Rows, followed by 256 - 500 Rows etc...?

Comment: I am confused as to what you are using OleDb for, can you explain that? Also why do you have 15000 columns, that seems highly impractical, do you have 15000 rows as well? Is there not a way to restructure this data into a more suitable form?

Comment: so I'm confused too for 15000 column! but my file structure is this. I cant edit that. rows cout is 900 and 15000 column. I have a resolve way in teorical! can i replace rows and columns in import level? go for 15000 rows and 900 columns ? and when i want save that, replace again rows and columns. it can resolve with use only 4 datagridview (I think).

Comment: Sorry man, your question is still too unclear. Are you reading 900, 15000 column records from an excel doc using OleDb... and then using the interop to write them to another excel file? Where is your problem - during the import stage or the export stage? Are you saying that you can only import 255 columns at a time? the select statement looks as though you are only importing 26 columns...?

Comment: I want Import a excel file with 900 Rows & 15000 Columns. But 255 column limit is Reason for i cant import directly from the file to a gridview. I want edit this data after importing in gridview, then save new data to other excel file. My problem is in both of import and export stage. in importing i have limit in 255 column.

Comment: I have a way for this problem. i can import only 255 column of excel file, Edit this 255, save in other file, then import next 255 column, edit 2nd 255 column , ...
in Export(Save) stage in this Conditions i have problem for saving sequential each 255 column in only A file.

Comment: Are you manually editing the data? It seems unlikely considering you have 900 x 15000 datapoints. Why do you need the gridview? Can you not edit the data programatically? You can use the interop to read the data into an object[,] array which could probably house it all in one shot...

Comment: Manualy ?!!! No, this is my code for add 1 too all of my cells. I edit My post ...

Comment: So you only want to add 1 to every cell? Then I don't understand why you are using a gridview...?

Comment: yes, only adding 1 to every cell. But I want repeat this work for example 5000 time !
can i do this without gridview ?

Comment: Definitely - Ill post a new answer

Comment: I edited my answer to show you a way of doing this without a gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int chunk = 0; chunk < TotalColumnsToImport/255; chunk++)             
{
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count; j++)
                {

                    ExcelApp.Cells[i + 1, chunk * 255 + j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();

                }

            }
}
```

I don't know if I have really understood your requirements but from what I can gather this is all you need to do. You are importing your data in chunks of 255 columns so just add another loop on the outside, keep track of which chunk you are on and then off set the columns by your chunk number times 255. In your case the TotalColumnsToImport variable used in the loop limit is 15000.

Your suggestion of transposing the data when you import it and again when you export it is a good one. In that case the TotalColumnsToImport becomes 900 and like you say, you can do this in only 4 iterations. I hope this helps.

Edit:

OK so I think you should not be using a gridview. Try this:

```
//Open the worksheet
            Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)currentWorkbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

            //Convert from interop object to native C# object, indexed 1 to length
            object[,] data = (object[,])ws.UsedRange.Value2;
```

now loop through data, instead of the gridview in your export stage and add 1 to each value before you write them:

```
for (int i = 1; i < data.GetLength(0); i++)
    {

        for (int j = 1; j < data.GetLength(1); j++)
        {

            ExcelApp.Cells[i, j] = (int)data[i,j] + 1;

        }

    }
```

You might have to fiddle a bit with the casting but it should work and be much faster. Also note that data[,] is indexed from 1 not 0 which is unusual.

Comment: Hey, its good idea to save from gridview with all of my 15000 column.
But i need 58 gridview ? or 58 time reclean my gridview and fill it (import) again with new 255 column.
is any way to transposing data in import stage ?

Comment: ofcourse - something like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44274/Transpose-a-DataTable-using-C. But I do not understand why you are using a gridview at all. Just use the interop to read in the data to an object[,] array. Like this: //Open the worksheet

                Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)currentWorkbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];


                //Convert from interop object to native C# object, indexed 1 to length

                object[,] data = (object[,])ws.UsedRange.Value2;

Comment: With the above edit you should not need to transpose, nor use a gridview.